# Using Core Animation with objects other than CALayers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I was pretty sure I had seen discussions of this around the Net, but now I can't seem to find anything. The question is simple: is there a way to use for example `CABasicAnimation` to animate a property on an object that's not a ´CALayer´? (Say, the ´volume´ property on an ´AVAudioPlayer´.)

If not, is there a way to make it work other than subclassing ´CALayer´? Maybe some protocol to conform to?

EDIT: How about doing this on the iPhone OS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can indeed do this. Your object must implement the [`NSAnimatablePropertyContainer`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSAnimatablePropertyContainer_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html) protocol and return a valid `CAAnimation` object for each property you want to animate in the `+defaultAnimationForKey:` class method.

To answer your updated question, no, you can't do this on the iPhone at present as there is no `NSAnimatablePropertyContainer` protocol available in iPhone OS and you can't get an `animator` proxy object from other objects.

Comment: Thanks Rob! Now the follow-up question: is this possible on the iPhone OS?

Comment: Any pointers as to how one would one go about implementing NSAnimatablePropertyContainer? Specifically the - (id)animator; method?

Comment: Similar answer by the same author with more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10168831/377384 (thanks Rob!)