# Proper way to label an NSAnimation for sorting animationDidEnd: messages

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nsanimation

My question is pretty straightforward : I have a class which is the delegate of several NSAnimations and I will need to give a name/identifier to my NSAnimation so that the sorting of all the `-(void)animationDidEnd:(NSAnimation *)animation` messages can be done easily.

Any ideas on how to achieve it ?

EDIT : Should I analyze the lack of answer as meaning that I shouldn't be using `NSAnimation` at all ?

Source : [Is NSAnimation deprecated ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166498/is-there-a-way-to-run-2-nsanimation-objects-simultaneously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out animations should be handled by [Core Animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coreanimation_guide/introduction/introduction.html) : it's more powerful than `NSAnimation`, more systematic and you can label your animation using a key :

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

CALayer* myLayer;

CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
anim.path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,100,100)];
anim.repeatCount = 0;
anim.duration = 3.0;
[bounceLayer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"MyAnimationKey"];
```

Furthermore, there are nice delegate methods such as : `- (void)animationDidStart:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation` to achieve what we had in mind.